# how to fetch the array values in separate variables

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TotalPaid] => 0
            [Description] => One-time: 
            [PayStatus] => 0
            [InvoiceTotal] => 34.78
            [TotalDue] => 34.78
            [JobId] => 66
            [DateCreated] => 20150311T02:57:10
            [Id] => 66
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TotalPaid] => 0
            [Description] => One-time: 
            [PayStatus] => 0
            [InvoiceTotal] => 89.06
            [TotalDue] => 89.06
            [JobId] => 68
            [DateCreated] => 20150311T02:58:27
            [Id] => 68
        )
)
```

i have ds array as a output this output is in a single variable ie $invoices.. i want each value in a separate variable...

Comment: What have you tried, as of now you're just asking "HEY! can you make it for me?" That's not how SO works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store an array as a variable you can access each value in the array by adding the name of the array key between `[]` brackets after the variable name. like so...

```
$invoices[0]['Description']
```

If you wanted to loop through your invoices you could do...

```
foreach( $invoices as $invoice ) {
    $description = $invoice['Description'];
}
```

If you need more info try the PHP manual - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**EDIT:** As Chris has pointed out the second example is only for use inside the loop because the example foreach would simply overwrite the variable at each iteration so you would need to do something immediately after its assignment within the iteration or it will be lost. However the first method would allow access to the value just increment the numeric key. from 0 to 1 and you would have both results assigned their own variable.

Hope that helps.

Dan

Comment: i hv to inserted it inside the email form like in $message="<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>TotalPaid</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>PayStatus</th>
<th>InvoiceTotal</th>
<th>InvoiceType</th>
<th>TotalDue</th>
<th>JobId</th>
<th>DateCreated</th>
<th>Id</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>".$e."</td>
<td>".$i."</td>
<td>".$h."</td>
<td>".$d."</td>
<td>".$g."</td>
<td>".$f."</td>
<td>".$b."</td>
<td>".$c."</td>
<td>".$a."</td>


</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
 bt this snds only first value.. i want to send all the value through mail..

Comment: @user4501586 You haven't been very clear on exactly what it is you want to do. Please include as much relevant code in your question as possible and give an example of what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the outer array, with a nested loop to go over the inner array. Within these, you can construct a string using the array keys (e.g. `'TotalPaid0'`, `'Description0'`, `...` `'TotalPaid1`', `'Description1'`, etc.) and then use Variable variables to store the values in.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

In response to user4501586 comment.

The code you posted to me makes no sense, you want to output to specific variables when actually to out put to that form you actually just need to call the relevant $array[0]['key'], $array[1]['key']

By this i mean select the appropriate array key and replace corresponding letter variable that you have chosen with it.

As has been suggested this is not a make me some code that works site, we are hear to help but you seem to want us to do it for you.

Also suggested. PHP Documentation you really should read up on it because i feel you do not yet grasp even the basics and that is something we cant help you with here.